# How to block requests from domain other than mine?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a wordpress website say mydomain.in, Someone is using domain masking and able to open my website on their domain(lets say external.com) without my permission. I have this .htaccess rules but its not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mydomain.in
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.in/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it still opens from their domain. What is the solution for this

Comment: Could you please try to put something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mydomain\.com [NC]` and see if that helps?

Comment: @anubhava, that's a great catch sir, you could post it as an answer IMHO.

Comment: @anubhava can u please elaborate? I didn't understand.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.in/? [R=301,L]

like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Take note of this new rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

That checks if `HTTP_HOST` of a request is not `mydomain.in` then simply block the request with `403 - Forbidden` status.

Comment: do i need to restart apache or anything else for new rules to be applied?

Comment: okay. https://www.kapdewaale.in/ this is my domain.. https://www.dsplzhyy.com/ this is external domain to be blocked. its still opening.

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: Domain `www.dsplzhyy.com` is registered in `JiangSu, China` so clearly not yours. It appears there may have been some hacking attempt on your website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224711/discussion-between-ashish-and-anubhava).